# Fancybox iframe not including with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

This might be a simple problem i have but i cant figure it out.

I have button, when i click on the button fancybox opens an iframe with a page of my website. It containts a simple form for sending a e-mail.
Everything works fine and all but i make use of the lib.phpmailer but i cant seem to include it.

```
include_once 'url/classes/lib.phpmailer.php';
```

The url that i am using is valid and leads to the phpmailer file. 
But the iframe does not include it.

Any idees how to resolve this?

Some code:

```
<a class="reserve" 
   href="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/pages/includes/reserveform.php"  
   id="reserve">
     Reserve
</a>

$("a#reserve").fancybox({
    'autoScale': true,
    'width': 460,
    'height': 440,
    'padding': 20,
    'showCloseButton': true,
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

reserveform.php

```
include_once 'url/classes/lib.phpmailer.php';
HTML and stuff
```

I also tried to include athor files, but none do work.

Comment: you are including a relative path. is the path to the file /pages/includes/url/classes/lib.phpmailer.php ?  are you able to load the page /pages/includes/reserveform.php in a browser and get the file loaded ?  are there any errors in your php errors log saying something along the lines of unable to open file ?

Comment: relative and full both dont work.
Atm url is 'http: //domain.nl/classes/lib.phpmailer.php'

Going to that url works in the browser

Comment: and you tried include_once '/classes/lib.phpmailer.php';  ?
like i asked before, are you seeing any errors in the php error log ? that is usually the best way to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what fancybox is, and a quick glance didn't tell me if the domains are the same but if not then you might need to add an iframe within your iframe that references the top parents domain to over come cross-domain restrictions?

Comment: @ lonewolf, yes that was my first approach. No result. @Samin not sure what you mean but the iframe is on the same domain as the request

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, which was pretty odd.

```
../../classes/lib.phpmailer.php
```

This one works. Weirdness that the absolute and relative path didnt work. Ah well since i use PHP and Javascript, there isnt much that doesnt suprise me.

My roots are programming in Java and PHP, javascript are a whole different bunch haha.

thanks for the replies